# Unable to GPU render with Mac

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, osx

I keep getting an error when trying to render Cycles using GPU:

> error: CUDA error: Out of memory in cuLaunchKernel (cuPathTrace, xblocks , yblocks, 1, xthreads, ythreads, 1, 0, 0, args, 0)

I am using the latest version of Blender, but have experienced this problem in every version so far.

I am on an iMac (from late 2012) with 8GB Ram, using Nvidia GeForce GTX 675MX 1024MB.

Even the simplest of scenes seems to produce this error.

According to the documentation my card should work for GPU rendering.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How much memory does the render take on cpu? If it's more than 900mb there might not be enough memory left in your GPU given the OS is using some of the memory as well.

Comment: 1GB of VRAM is not a lot. Specially if that is the only GPU on your system, as some it is already used by whatever is on the display. Close all other applications running in the background, simplify your scene as much as you can, work with smaller textures. If none of that works... you are stuck rendering in CPU...

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/why-are-there-scenes-that-will-not-render-on-gpu-but-will-render-fine-on-cpu/24207#24207

Comment: Thanks guys, I guessed I was stuck on cpu, but thanks for confirming that

Comment: i had the same problem. Same mac and 2.77 blender version.
I found the tips in this post https://developer.blender.org/T42287 Now i'm rendering in blender cycles with blender 2.71a on GPU. sometime my imac has a crash and need to restart..