# I have a CUDA error when rendering

Tags: rendering

Hi I am running Athlon X2 with 6 gig of ram and a gtx75o card I just bought.

I try and render and it says

CUDA error: Out of memory in cuMemAlloc(&device_pointer, size)

Comment: It helps to do a quick search in the future, https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cuda+error, your problem might have already been asked and solved.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/why-are-there-scenes-that-will-not-render-on-gpu-but-will-render-fine-on-cpu