# Blender 2.83 GPU render slows compared to CPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, gpu, performance

I am doing animations for over 3 years and i never came across the scenario that GPU render slower than CPU.
I m currently rendering a scene and the same scene is being rendered by CPU in 9 minutes and bu GPU in 47 minutes in cycles
**CPU : Ryzen 7 2700x
GPU : GTX 1060 3GB**

My question is that is this scenario makes sense because if you compare benchmarks both are more of less equal in render times ,, so why such a difference?
Is scene dependent on CPU or GPU or is there something wrong with either my software or hardware?

Comment: You didn't tell about your scene or how complicated it is. Start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24272/gpu-slower-than-cpu and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/why-are-there-scenes-that-will-not-render-on-gpu-but-will-render-fine-on-cpu

Comment: Nothing strange about it. A multithreaded CPU can render many tiles simultaneously, GPU renders one. A fast and multicore CPU might outperform a single GPU. IIT !ight make a difference if you enable Optix in the render settings instead of CUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
I was using Blender 2.83.1 version
but 2 days ago new version came and i installed that and render times are around 4 5 minutes which is perfect.
So this was some kind of bug that is fixed now by blender.